# Sendgrid makes links to others - Get them made right

Tags: c#, sendgrid

That's how I've added a regular link to the bottom of email if the customer would like to unsubscribe from newsletter, but Sendgrid has turned it into an incredibly long email.

[image]

Then my question is: How can I change it to my own link or link that is smaller? - I'd just like to make it shorter or less so customers do not think it's spam

It's like I can not upload image so I can show it here.

Code:

```
var viewModel = new EmailModel
{
    getUrl = link, //link to remove user from newsletterlist here
    Title = title, //title for email
    FullName = item.Navn, //name on the user
    text = text.ToHtmlString() //text value
};

var resultMail = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Templates/newMail.cshtml", viewModel);//return Null here

MailMessageControl mail = new MailMessageControl();
mail.SetCredentials(m.azureName(), m.password());
mail.SetSender(m.mailFrom());
mail.AddAddressSee(item.Brugernavn);
mail.SetSubject(title);
mail.SetBody(Regex.Replace(resultMail, "<[^>]*>", ""));

mail.SendEmail();
await Task.Delay(2200);
```

Comment: You can probably use HTML formatting and use `anchor` tag to hide the long url.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can find information about it? @hendryanw

Comment: if i try `<a href="@Model.getUrl">` Then you can not click any link at all and you can not see any link at all.

Comment: Can you include the code to compose the email in the question?

Comment: Yea i have this now. @hendryanw

Comment: It seems your `Regex.Replace(resultMail, "<[^>]*>", "")` is replacing the braces with empty string, so the HTML tag does not work. And try to use the anchor tag with some text: `<a href="@Model.getUrl">Subscribe</a>`

Comment: @hendryanw Now I've tried to take it away but nothing happens. I still can not add links or resemble.

Comment: Can you check whether the `resultMail` value is properly HTML formatted? Try to render it locally in your browser and see if it is working.

Comment: Ohh this work now @hendryanw but now i see HTML-tags ind email. U can see here: https://gyazo.com/85d63ccee5e70f2fc07c15d662611b9a

Comment: Okay, but it should render the HTML not printing it as plain-text. Maybe you missed the `<html></html>` tag itself.

Comment: Sure.. xD @hendryanw Thanks!